# Want to hide this div when click is outside, exclude any click inside it

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Detect click outside element?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1160880/detect-click-outside-element)

Im trying to hide a div when focus (click) is outside it, but there are some elements in it and instead of doing the e.target.id on all these is there a way to include all elements? is it clear what i mean?

EDIT: im trying to `hide` the `#contain_name` when anybody `click` outside the `newsletter`

jsfiddle: [demo](http://jsfiddle.net/FUDLk/8/)

```
<div id="newsletter">
    <form action="#" class="form-post">
        <div class="clearfix">
            <input type="text" id="email" name="email" placeholder="email" />
            <button id="fake">Send</button>
        </div>
        <div id="contain_name" class="clearfix">
            <input type="text" id="person_name" placeholder="full name" />
            <button id="real_button">Send</button>
        </div>
    </form> 
</div> 


$('#email').focus(function() {
    $('#fake').fadeOut();
    $('#contain_name').slideDown();
});

$(document).on('click', function(){
    //do something here
});
```

Comment: Which DIV are you referring to?

Comment: @FrançoisWahl I think this post got some valuable answers for anybody trying to learn this, and is a bit different.

Comment: @Dejan.S: It is a duplicate question and the answers are near identical as well. One is using `$(...)[0]` check while the other uses `$(...).length`. It is the same difference, they both check that the jQuery selector matched something before executing the relevant code segment. Anything additional you learn in consequence on how jQuery works adds to the value of the answer but still makes the question a duplicate I'm afraid.

Comment: @FrançoisWahl does not matter if it gets marked as duplicate, if anybody can learn from whats in it. i get your point tho.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This?

```
$( document ).on( 'click', function ( e ) {
    if ( !$( e.target ).closest( '#newsletter' )[0] ) {
        $( '#contain_name' ).hide();
    }
});
```

**Live demo:** http://jsfiddle.net/FUDLk/11/

Comment: wont work, http://jsfiddle.net/FUDLk/9/

Comment: @Dejan.S You forgot to define the argument `e`. Working demo: http://jsfiddle.net/FUDLk/11/

Comment: oh, i did :), care to explain why you use the `array[0]` here and what it does?

Comment: @ŠimeVidas: Your current example also hides the **fake** send button. Maybe adding `$('#fake').fadeIn();` will re-set it to the original state if clicked outside it.

Comment: @FrançoisWahl The "Send" button is only displayed if the user focuses the #email field.

Comment: I'm gone work out the details with show and hide later, its just that click outside bothering me

Comment: @Dejan.S:If all you wanted to know is how to detect the click outside the element it seems to be a duplicate of `http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1160880/detect-click-outside-element`

Comment: @Dejan.S `$( e.target ).closest( '#newsletter' )` searches for the #newsletter element within the ancestor chain of the event target. If the user clicked within that element, than it will be found in the ancestor chain, and the jQuery object will select it. Otherwise, the jQuery object will contain no elements. Now, `[0]` returns the first element from the jQuery object, which is either the #newsletter element, or `null` if the jQuery object was empty. Finally, `!` negates that expression, since we want the if-branch to execute only if the jQuery object didn't contain any elements.

Comment: sort of, my situation was also all the element inside it too, which i see this also is. but the approach @ŠimeVidas provide is a bit different with the `array[0]`

Comment: You could use `Array.length` instead

Comment: @Alexander any specific reason to use the `Array.lenght` instead? and how to use that approach? `Array.length > 0`?

Comment: @Alexander For me, it makes more sense grab the first element from the jQuery object and check if it's a DOM element, since that is what I'm trying to determine anyways. My method is more direct.

Comment: @Dejan.S He is referring to `if ( $( e.target ).closest( '#newsletter' ).length === 0 ) { ...` which behaves the same.

Comment: @ŠimeVidas thanks for explaining. learned something useful here.

Answer (score 2):

```
$(document).on('click', function(e){
    if (e.target !== $("#excludedDiv")[0]) {
      // do something there
    }
});
```

Comment: +1, sorry i didn't notice who went first at first.